# How to make javascript code stop running offline?

Tags: javascript, html, offline

I'm making a model viewer online with Javascripts. For security reason, i don't want user can run it anywhere out of my site.

I already obfucated and lock domain but if user download whole website, they still can run offline.

So, how to detect that user is running offline and stop working by Javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: I thought javascript is wholly downloaded to the client by design.

Comment: Javascript isn't a great solution for security reasons, the recipient can always disable Javascript

Comment: @Nicholas Kyriakides My javascript is already obfucated by commercial software so it's quite hard to see, understand and moddifier by most user.

Comment: @user972611 I'm sorry, i misunderstood the question. Now i get it. I think the most concrete solution would be to have your app depend on some server-side code to function. That will complicate the design/scalability but if the security you are looking for is worth it then the trade off is fine, it's wholly up to you to decide. I would move some of my complex math to the server for example. That's my 2 cents.  Before you start complicating things, make sure you are not paranoid about this, because many people fall into the ''MY PRECIOUS CODE, NOOO'' trap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var checkAfter=15; //15 seconds
  setTimeOut(CheckNavigatorState,checkAfter*1000);

function CheckNavigatorState(){
   if(navigator.onLine){
       //  --- Add javascript src OR call js functions here
   }else{       
      //----remove javascript source OR stop functions    
    setTimeOut(CheckNavigatorState,checkAfter*1000);
   }
}
```

I would like to mention that it is not easy to tell whether the browser is offline or not.
Some browser vendors say the browser is offline when computer loose its connection to the network, which is not really exact. We know that you can have access to the LAN but not to the internet. So to do what you may need to ping a real distant server, such as `Google`.

EDITS: To ping with JavaScript, check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tresorunikin/GSSCD/507/) (edited)

Answer (score 0):

You could make the javascript code check the domain it is running on using the window.location property (http://www.roberthalf.com/technology/External_Sites/content/RHT-NA3/Shared/Images/logos/rht_logo_c.gif) but that will only keep people who don't know how to modify javascript code from running it locally.  The better solution would be to make your code dependent on something on the server so that whenever they try to do something important it makes an ajax call to the server, which can then check the referrer and return an error if they aren't running from the server.